# PHP Use include with whitespaces?

Tags: php, include

I am including a textfile from a PHP file, using:

```
include("thesocalledfile.txt");
```

But when it prints out, it doesn't happear to show the whitespaces, \n, etc.

Comment: Do you print it to html? If so you have to view source to see the new lines as \r\n isn't html

Comment: @JimL thanks, I will use javascript to make a replace of \n to <br> and stuff

Comment: currently, you're including a file. You should actually open/read the file and then output the content. See answer below. I'm assuming you are trying to output to html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are displaying text to a browser, you will need to append HTML formatting to it, or stick it inside a set of `<pre></pre>` tags.

The simplest way to add in line breaks and so forth in php is [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php).

```
<?php
echo nl2br("foo isn't\n bar");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have plain text line breaks you can try

```
 $fh = fopen("filename.txt", 'r');

    $pageText = fread($fh, 25000);

    echo nl2br($pageText);
```

you need the nl2br to wrap the text

You can also set up `<pre></pre>` tags and output the file inside them.